# 16.04 Can't login after sleep - Clearing orphaned inode

Tags: login, suspend, hibernate, inode

I put my computer in sleep before going home from work. When I got in the next morning moving the mouse and hitting the keyboard wouldn't wake it up.  So I held the power button for a hard shutdown.  After that, it will turn on, but when I try to log in it's rejected (booted back to login screen).

No updates, no new drivers, just a sleep followed by a hard power off.

While logging in, the command line says:

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clearing orphaned inode 44312435 (uid=100, gid =114, node = 0100664, size = 2200)
(similar output clearing 5 inodes total)
/dev/sda1: clean, 496639/60530688 files, 11181092/232110720 blocks
```

Anyone have any idea how I could log in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Reinstall nvidia drivers.  Downloaded them from a different computer onto a USB flash drive.  Manually mounted the flash drive

```
sudo mkdir /media/usb
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

Then:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA_DRIVER_375.66
```

Follow the instructions, reboot - golden.

Good luck.